# Hide and show markers in a Leaflet map using zoomend

Tags: leaflet

How to hide and show markers in a Leaflet map using `zoomend`.

Example [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kedar2a/5VLJU/8/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove a layer holding the markers, then you could turn them on again.
Is that what you are thinking?[update of your fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/tlohnes/c10ysagv/)

Just make sure to add each marker to the layer Group, not the map.

```
L.geoJson(geojsonFeature, {

    pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng){

        marker = L.marker(e.latlng, {

            title: "Resource Location",
            alt: "Resource Location",
            riseOnHover: true,
            draggable: true,

        }).bindPopup("<input type='button' value='Delete this marker' class='marker-delete-button'/>");

        marker.on("popupopen", onPopupOpen);

        return marker;
    }
}).addTo(layerGroup);
}
```

Comment: thanks for solution.  But i need Hide and show with positioned markers in a Leaflet map using zoomend. Example [link](http://jsfiddle.net/c10ysagv/17/). Any idea?

Comment: I am not understanding your request. That seems like the original fiddle you started with. You want to turn a layer of markers on and off? You said turn it off with zoomend which is what I showed you. When do you want to turn it on.

Comment: Now i want to only display markers at the zoomed area. example [link](http://jsfiddle.net/c10ysagv/20/). Idea, or solution?